# can telnet into MaxScale but can't connect with MySQL console

Tags: proxy, proxy-server, maxscale

I am attempting to connect to a server with MaxScale on it (which in turn is connected to a master/multiple slaves setup). I can telnet to the MaxScale IP and port but can't connect using the MySQL console. Any ideas?

Comment: Posting more information would be helpful e.g. what port is MaxScale listening on and what is the exact MySQL console command you use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am successfully using telnet as "telnet 124.139.36.127 4006." The MySQL console command I am using is "mysql -h 124.139.36.127 --port=4006 -u evan -p"

Comment: Finally got it, I just had to add some permissions to my master/slaves (I had initially thought the MySQL console command specified a MaxScale user but it should actually specify a user from the MySQL machines).

Comment: I'd suggest resolving this question with your own answer, it might help other users.